# How to define array of generic classes in swift

Tags: swift

I have several classes for cells data with `CellDataBase` as base class. Main idea is that I can define new cell data class and pair it with cell by generic.

```
public class CellBase { }

public class CellA: CellBase { }

public class CellB: CellBase { }


public class CellDataBase<U: CellBase> {
    var cellType: U.Type = U.self
}

class CellDataA: CellDataBase<CellA> { }

class CellDataB: CellDataBase<CellB> { }
```

Is it possible to define array and store `CellDataA`, `CellDataB` etc. in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible because there is **no** common type ancestor to `CellDataA` and `CellDataB`.  You might *think* that `CellDataBase` is a common ancestor but it is not; the introduction of the `U` type parameter means that for each type `U` there is a totally distinct type.

You might try something like this:

```
protocol CellDataBase {
  // avoid `Self` and `associatedType`
  // ...

  var count : UInt { get } // number of items in database..

  // ...
}

public class StandardCellDataBase<U: CellBase> : CellDataBase { ... }
class CellDataA: StandardCellDataBase <CellA> { }
class CellDataB: StandardCellDataBase <CellB> { }
```

and then:

```
var databases = [CellDataBase]()
```

Note that defining `CellDataBase` as a protocol that avoid "Self and associated types requirements" might be difficult, depending on your needs.

**====**

Another similar option, assuming you can't change your definition of `CellDataBase` is to define another protocol and add it as an extension to `CellDataBase`.  Like such:

```
protocol GenericCellDataBase {
  var count : UInt { get }
}

extension CellDataBase : GenericCellDataBase {
  var count : UInt { return ... }
}

var databases = [GenericCellDataBase]()
```

Comment: Nice point, I'd replaced `protocol CellDataBase` to `class CellDataBase` and it also works.